# Setting minimum temperature for gas water heater

Tags: heater, temperature

My gas water heater heats water in its tank to about 60 C for use which is great. But I don't know how to set a minimum temperature so that water does not cool below 30 C. Please help me.

Comment: While it's not likely that you can set a _minimum_, providing the make & model of the water heater would help us confirm that. Please [edit] that into your post.

Comment: If your water heater set to 60°C is cooling below 30°C, options are: you are exceeding it's capacity to heat water, or it's broken. More likely the former. A water heater stores a certain amount of hot water, and can heat water at a certain rate. When you draw more hot water than it has stored, at a rate faster than it can heat water, the delivered temperature of the water will fall, even though the thermostat is running the burner full-bore.

Comment: What is your water heater model. Mine never fluctuates low enough for me to tell a difference. Mine is at 54 C and it always feels constant. Do you have some sort of WiFi enabled system? Maybe someone is messing with you. Quite honestly the water heater sounds faulty.

Comment: Is this a pressurized hot water tank that fills automatically as hot water is drawn? Or is this a batch tank which does not automatically replace hot water as it is used?

Answer (score 2):

In a standard gas water heater there is no way to set a minimum hot water temperature. The thermostatic control has a pre set on/off differential.